# Issues running rails 6 app on heroku - NoMethodError: undefined method `deep_symbolize_keys' for "postgresql":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to push my web app (rails backend, react frontend) online. The front end is up and seems to be functioning on netlify, the back end is on heroku and I'm running into errors. It works fine on the development build but I'm getting errors related to 'deep_symbolize_keys' on heroku and the app is crashing. From what I can see from digging through things, 'deep_symbolize_keys' was deprecated in rails 5.1 (I'm running rails 6.0.3.4). However it is specifically deprecated with respect to ActiveRecord as that's no longer a hash, I've confirmed it's still in the docs for version 6.0. I've also confirmed that I'm running the latest version of the gems that seem to be expressing issues.

From research I've attempted to add this in a couple of spots (environment.rb, application.rb, puma.rb):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/keys'
```

```
Puma starting in single mode...
app[web.1]: * Version 5.0.2 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Spoony Bard
app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
app[web.1]: * Environment: production
app[web.1]: ! Unable to load application: NoMethodError: undefined method `deep_symbolize_keys' for "postgresql":String
app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma)
app[web.1]: NoMethodError: undefined method `deep_symbolize_keys' for "postgresql":String
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:44:in `store_translations'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:230:in `block in load_file'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:230:in `each'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:230:in `load_file'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `block in load_translations'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `each'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `load_translations'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:80:in `init_translations'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:65:in `eager_load!'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.5/lib/i18n.rb:76:in `eager_load!'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:123:in `each'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:123:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
app[web.1]:   /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:330:in `load_rackup'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:256:in `app'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:131:in `load_and_bind'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/single.rb:44:in `run'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/launcher.rb:171:in `run'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Edit: I was asked to include my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ten_athletes_api_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: ten_athletes_api_test

production:
  <<: *default
  url: "postgres://.... (edited)"
  database: ten_athletes_api_production
  username: ten_athletes_api
  password: EDITED OUT
```

Comment: Please post the content from your `config/database.yml` file hiding passwords

Comment: I updated the post to include it at the bottom. (Sorry, your response caught me on a day off)